# Excel - How to calculate a columns, based on three fields (filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the staffing numbers at my work. I am trying to calculate the full-time (1) and part-time (0.5)

[image]

This is the formula I am using at the minute

```
=COUNTIFS('Employee Mapping'!H:H,"Director",'Employee Mapping'!F:F, "Marketing")
```

.........Employee Mapping is another tab

However, the above formula is pulling the number to state 1 employee is a Director who works in Marketing. I want to know if they work full time (1) is part time (0.5)

If i added another column which shows 1 = Full time // 0.5 = Part time ... how would I pull this through. For example: The director works Part Time

I want it to show 0.5, instead of 1.

Thanks

Comment: can you show a bit more data (with a screenshot perhaps) and an example of your optimal output?

Comment: I can't share a screenshot as it contains sensative data. However,

Comment: I can't share a screenshot as it contains sensative data. However, the main columns are:_

Name: Joe Bloggs
Department: Marketing
Team: Digital
Level: Manager
Role Status: 1(Full time) 0.5(Part time)

Using '=COUNTIFS('Employee Mapping'!H:H,"**Director**",'Employee Mapping'!F:F, "**Marketing**")'

This shows one person has Director and Marketing associated to them. 

I want to include role status. So, instead of it showing we have one marketing director, i want it to show their role status - 0.5 part time.
- Marketing Director - 1

I want it to show
- Marketing Director - 0.5

Comment: I can't share a screenshot as it contains sensative data. However, the main columns are:_

Name: Joe Bloggs
Department: Marketing
Team: Digital
Level: Manager
Role Status: 1(Full time) 0.5(Part time)

Using '=COUNTIFS('Employee Mapping'!H:H,"**Director**",'Employee Mapping'!F:F, "**Marketing**")'

This shows one person has Director and Marketing associated to them. 

I want to include role status. So, instead of it showing we have one marketing director, i want it to show their role status - 0.5 part time.
- Marketing Director - 1

I want it to show
- Marketing Director - 0.5

Comment: Make up some data that is **realistic**.  It doesn't need to be **real**